# Retrieving All Articles Titles from an XML Wiki Dump - Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have a Wikipedia XML dump created by exporting all pages of a certain category. You can see the exact structure of this XML file by generating one for yourself at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export. Now I would like to make a list, in Python, of the titles of each article. I have tried using:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('./comp_sci_wiki.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for element in root:
    for sub in element:
        print sub.find("title")
```

Nothing is printed. This seems like it should be a relatively straightforward task. Any help you could provide would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the beginning of the exported file, you'll see that the document declares a default XML namespace:

```
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLo
```

That means there is no un-namespaced "title" element in the document,
which is one reason why your `sub.find("title")` statement is failing.
You can see this if you were to print out your `root` element:

```
>>> print root
<Element '{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}mediawiki' at 0x7f2a45df6c10>
```

Note that it doesn't say `<Element 'mediawiki'>`.  The identifier includes the full namespace.  [This document](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) describes in detail how to work with namespaces in XML document, but the tl;dir version is that you need:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> tree=ET.parse('/home/lars/Downloads/Wikipedia-20160405005142.xml')
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> ns = 'http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/
>>> for page in root.findall('{%s}page' % ns):
...   print (page.find('{%s}title' % ns).text)
... 
Category:Wikipedia books on computer science
Computer science in sport
Outline of computer science
Category:Unsolved problems in computer science
Category:Philosophy of computer science
[...etc...]
>>>
```

That that your life would probably be easier if you were to install
the `lxml` module, which includes full xpath support, allowing you to
do something like this:

```
>>> nsmap={'x': 'http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/'}
>>> for title in tree.xpath('//x:title', namespaces=nsmap):
...   print (title.text)
... 
Category:Wikipedia books on computer science
Computer science in sport
Outline of computer science
Category:Unsolved problems in computer science
Category:Philosophy of computer science
Category:Computer science organizations
[...etc...]
```

Anyway, read through the docs on namespace support and hopefully that
plus these examples will point you in the right direction.  The
takeaway should be that XML namespaces are important, and `title` in
one namespace is not the same as `title` in another namespace.